# The class 'List' doesn't have an unnamed constructor

Tags: flutter, list, dart, model

I am trying to write a model but i keep getting this error. Here is the code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CardModel {
late List<CardResults> results;

CardModel({ required this.results});

CardModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
if (json['cardResults'] != null) {
  results = List<CardResults>();
  json['cardResults'].forEach((v) {
    results.add(CardResults.fromJson(v));
  });
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`List<CardResults>()` is no longer valid Dart code as of Dart 3.0.
See https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/49529 for details.

You can instead use `<CardResults>[]`. But personally, I prefer creating the completed list at the declaration, rather than creating an empty list and building it up.

Answer (score 5):

First, `List` type doesn't have a default constructor so doing `List()` is not possible. So, instead you can create an empty list using `<CardResults>[]` or `List<CardResults>.empty()`.

You can learn more about available constructors for `List` type [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.3/dart-core/List-class.html#constructors).

---

Second, you can optimize your code and instead of creating an empty list and calling add for each item you can use `map` method, like:

```dart
CardModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  if (json['cardResults'] != null) {
    results = json['cardResults'].map<CardResults>((v) => CardResults.fromJson(v)).toList();
  }
}
```

You can learn more about `map` method [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/map.html).

---

Third, instead of marking a property as `late` you can make it `final` and use `factory constructor` to instantiate an object. Finally, your `CardModel` should look like this:

```dart
class CardModel {
  final List<CardResults> results;

  CardModel({required this.results});

  factory CardModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return CardModel(
      results: json['cardResults']?.map<CardResults>((v) => CardResults.fromJson(v)).toList() ?? [],
    );
  }
}
```

You can learn more about factory constructors [here](https://dart.dev/language/constructors#factory-constructors).

Comment: This is a better answer than mine!  Should have gotten the check.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are getting the list of results from a JSON, you can map get the model list like this:

```
class CardModel {
//assuming your list is a list of strings
List<String> results;

CardModel({required this.results});

factory CardModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  if (json['cardResults'] != null) {
  return CardModel(
      results: List<String>.from(json["cardResults"].map((x) => x)));
 }
 // return an empty list if cardResults is empty
 return CardModel(results: []);
 }
}
```